# CNN model for timeseries prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, lstm

I want to build a CNN model. I have x_train=8000000x7, y_train=8000000x2.
Since it is a multivariant time series. How can feed the input with window size of 160 and stride=1.

what should be the input for cnn model?

I used timeseriesgenerator for creating a dataset as follows

```
train_gen = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.TimeseriesGenerator(X_train, Y_train,
                                                                length=160, sampling_rate=1,shuffle=False, batch_size=256)


batch_0  = train_gen[0]
data, label = batch_0
print("Shape of the generator data and label:", data.shape, label.shape)

input=data.shape[1],data.shape[2]
```

For LSTM I have used 'input' as the input shape. What should be the input for CNN model.

1)can use timeseriesgeneartor for CNN model?
2) is there any datagenerator for creating a sliding window approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `TimeseriesGenerator` is deprecated and do not take tensorflow tensor as input so I discourage to use it. Instead you can use `timeseries_dataset_from_array` (doc [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/timeseries_dataset_from_array)) from keras utils. It also generate sliding windows.

For time serie prediction, you should use 1-D CNN. They take a sequence as input exactly like LSTM. As shape is concerned, in Tensorflow it is still:

```py
input = data.shape[1], data.shape[2]
```

Assuming that `data.shape[0]` is the batch size, `data.shape[1]` the sequence length and `data.shape[2]` the number of features of each elements.

Comment: I have problem with memory size if I use **timeseries_dataset_from_array**, Is there any other generator I can use.

Comment: Also do you happen to know any article which explains working of convolution with time series data. I am having trouble understanding how it works with time series.

Comment: You can try to move your full data to CPU memory using numpy array insead tf tensor to save GPU memory.
CNNs 1D work like CNNs 2D. For each output feature (= channel) C_out, there is a kernel of size K*C_in that is applied in all series of K consecutive input samples. The sum of the values got for the application of the kernel centered on a sample is the value of the output feature for this sample. You halso have the notions of stride, dilatation and padding.

Comment: So, if my input to model is (160,7) (seq_length, feature), c_in will be 7 and K is 160 ? how to choose kernel size ?

Comment: c_in is 7 but K is the kernel size that is what you want. Generally you can chose K constant over all layer, the value depend on the number of layers you want and the sequence lenght. Basically for a length 160, I would chose K quite high like K=10,15 for 4-7 layers

Comment: Thank you, it helped to improve my model. But I am getting val_loss larger than training_loss and Why can't we use max_pooling here ?

Comment: It is very classic to have a gap between val and train for time serie. It is simply because the series of the train are harder to predict that in validation. You can try to decrease the loss of the val the most you can without taking account for the gap between the two losses. You can use max pooling like in CNN 2D to reduce the size of the sequence (basically to 1 for seq-to-one prediction). If you want a seq-to-seq prediction, you should not have pooling.